# Halo 3: ODST achievement — "Killing things that are new and different is bad/good"

Tags: achievements, halo-3-odst

When I played through *Halo 3: ODST* I saw the "squids" and killed them when I saw them, and got a counter (1 of 10, 2 of 10, 3 of 10, etc) toward the achievement, "Killing things that are new and different is bad". Eventually, like in the scene when I'm in a banshee escorting the phantom through the city, when I would kill the squids, I wouldn't get that counter anymore, so I could never finish the achievement. On the other hand, I never saw ANY reference when I played toward getting the "good" version of the achievement. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this, or why I might have stopped "getting credit" for my squid kills, and what the difference between the good and bad versions of this achievement is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so the way to get the "bad" version is:

- Only killing Engineers (that's what the squids are called) in the night time story count (ie. where you get the missions from)
- There are ONLY 10 of them
- You can miss one, which the Brutes are killing

To get the "good" version you have to only avoid killing these 10 (ones in the individual missions don't count) and save the one from the Brutes

Here is a map of the 10 engineer locations (and incidentally the audio logs)

[image]

I found the map at AchievementHunter.com

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! So does that mean that there isn't any type of "counter" for the good version, like there is for the bad version?

Comment: @rov that is correct, its hard to tell if you don't do something you can do right up till its considered done.  In this case the last mission